# .env file fails to pass string value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working in a react project and an API call completes successfully when the string value is directly entered. It fails when using the .env file

```
require('dotenv').load();

export default () => {

  const postToApi = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(process.env.API_POST_URL, {step : "3"})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  };
```

And here is my .env file in the root project folder:

```
NODE_PATH=./node_modules

API_POST_URL=http://localhost:4000/api/donate
```

The browser console error when executing the above function:

```
isURLSameOrigin.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:51)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:106)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:18)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:49)
```

package.json dependency object lists: `"dotenv": "^6.1.0"`

Does anyone know why the variable is not passing correctly?

Comment: Did you also install  dotenv using NPM?

Comment: This issue happened a while back but I believe the fix was to prefix `REACT_APP_` in the env variable key. React installs dotenv and loads its on its own when using create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env')});

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem simply because `dotenv.config({ path: "/.config/config.env" });`
was the incorrect path and I should have used `dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });`

Double check your path.

Answer (score -2):

Dont you need to put strings in env files within qoutes like `NODE_PATH = "./node_modules"`

What do you get if you `console.log(process.env.API_POST_URL);`

Just checked the dotenv docs and it says to use ` require('dotenv').config()'

Comment: Ok, I just tried adding double quotes around the string value in the .env file. It results in the same error unfortunately

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer and you don't need to put quotes in `.env` file it by default read as string

Comment: It would not let add comment till 50 reps, oddly I can comment on your comment